# PHP MySQL database connection using x10hosting

Tags: php

I am currently working on my database to keep my customer's name,birthday,email. In order to send email two weeks prior to customer's birthday.

I have followed "Derek Banas" youtube tutorial but when I tried to access to my code there were several errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLD9f.png

I realized there were path error when I use this code

```
require_once('http://grillontherock.x10host.com/CustomerInfo/mysqli_connect.php');
```

I put my files in the necessary location(I think)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17vtd.png

Some guy told me to use x10host but I really do not know main purpose of this hosting website.

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: What would be the ideal code to bring php? I am really new to php and mysql T-T

Comment: You do not need the full domain etc, use a relative path like `require_once './mysqli_connect.php';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `require_once` is used in one of the other files shown in that second picture, you shouldn't use the whole URL like that. `require_once` takes a file path, and a path relative to the file doing the requiring will work. Since the file your including is in the same directory, you should be able to just use

```
require_once 'mysqli_connect.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I **strongly** recommended against including remote PHP files in your code. You don't have control over the contents which could change without warning. This is especially dangerous when databases are involved.

I recommended getting the PHP source of that `mysqli_connect.php` file, adding it to your project, and then requiring it from there.

On a related note, you would need to set `allow_url_include` to true in your `php.ini` file per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) in order to successfully require remote scripts by URL. But again, **please** do not do this.

Comment: I think he is including it from his own site, but using the full url when it is unnecessary

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That is less dangerous than including code from another site, but definitely unnecessary as you said.

Comment: yeah I am including from my own site and  "require_once 'mysqli_connect.php';" this worked